# Uncheck row checkbox if inputs are empty on blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, each, blur

I have 2 issues here. Clicking an input on a row should check the row's checkbox. Currently, only the first text input will check the checkbox because of .prev(). Is there a different way to do this? All inputs for that row should check that row's checkbox.

```
// check checkbox for clicked row
            $('table').on('click', 'input[type=text]', function () {
                $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').prop('checked', true);
            });
```

Also, the second block of code isn't working as it should. If you focus on a different row, if the text inputs from the previous (or any) row are blank - remove the checkbox. The checkbox will be a save, and there is no point of saving blank text inputs.

```
// remove check in inputs are empty for that row
            $('input[type=text]').blur(function () { 
                $('table tr').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).find('input[type=text]:empty').length()) {
                        $('td').find('input').prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });
            })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldge5qzn/

Comment: Solution for #1: Look for the closest 'tr', rather than 'td'. $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('checked', true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the closest tr instead and then find the inputs that are checkboxes and set the checked property

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

For the second part, the :empty selector tests against the element having child elements not against empty values so that has to also be modified. Loop through each rows text inputs set a flag if any of them are not empty. Set checkbox accordingly

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
    var emptyRow = true;
    $(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
           emptyRow = false;   
        }
    });        
    if (emptyRow) {
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldge5qzn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking the closest `tr` - then finding the checkbox in that tr

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[type=text]', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Same thing with the second problem - check using the closest tr

Then you can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get all the text inputs with values

Then check the length to see if there are any inputs returned - and set the checked property accordingly using [.prop('checked',function()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function)

```
$('input[type=text]').blur(function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // get closest tr
    // get all of input[type=text] with value in that row
    var inputsWithValue = $tr.find('input[type=text]').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length;
    });
    // set the checked to true if any element has value - else set checked to false
    $tr.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function () {
        return inputsWithValue.length;
    }).length;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8L6ke8hp/)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this .Hope this helps ...

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[type=text]', function () {
                $(this).closest('td').parent('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            });
```

full code below :-

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alokbhat/ude4et6h/1/)